# nginx /admin /login wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, nginx

I want to setup simpler urls in nginx to login into wordpress i.e. /admin /login in nginx

I have tried multiple ways of tackling this with no luck.  any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred method is to use NO IF-STMTS:

```
# Login Short Cut
location ~* /login/ {
    rewrite ^/login/(.*)? /wp-admin/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Login Short Cut
if ($uri ~* "/login") {
    rewrite ^/login(/.*)? /wp-admin$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the above rewrite should allow a user to access the wordpress login screen by visiting mysite.com/login

I've included the above rewrite in the appropriate nginx config file

I'm using Wp-Skeleton which means the directory structure looks like this:

/wp/wp-admin.php
/wp/wp-login.php

When I access mysite.com/login it redirects to mysite.com/wp/wp-login.php

Is my assumption wrong and is there a way to rewrite to the more user friendly /login and /admin urls?

Only solution I can think of is to 301 redirect wp-login.php to /login